# Is there an automated tool that allows splitting a non-last git commit into multiple smaller commits?

Tags: git, rebase

(In this question, I'm assuming that you intend to split a commit that exists in your private repo only, and that you are otherwise being well-behaved about your git commit management.)

There are quite a few pages on teh Internets that describe how one can split the last commit into multiple ones.  tl;dr the approach is to do a soft reset to previous commit, then do an interactive commit.

Considerably fewer describe what to do if the commit you want to split is not the last one, but instead one that you stacked multiple things on top of.

I also have an idea what needs to be done to do this manually.  I would grow a branch from the commit I want to split, checkout that new branch, then apply the same procedure as described above.  Once done, rebase the original branch on top of the new one.

Now I can do this from the git command line, but you may have noticed that this is quite a bit of busywork.  Assuming no out-of-line modifications, it should be possible to automate this fully.  In fact, Mercurial has `hg csplit` which I think does exactly this, with visual assistance.

So my question is: have I missed a git-based tool that is able to automate this procedure?

Comment: `hg histedit` isn't automated any more than `git rebase -i` is automated; are you looking for `git rebase -i`?

Comment: Oops, I meant `hg csplit`...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an `hg csplit` (certainly not in my hg, although it's sadly out of date now). I found [a `csplit` utility](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/csplit.1.html) that's not part of Mercurial. I've found one reference to `hg csplit` via google, but no actual description of what it might do.